# Execute SQL Task Failing

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis

[image]I have this issue with my Execute SQL Task Failing. I am trying to execute a sp using an execute sql task. The execute statement is contained in a variable (exec [sp_name] par1, par2)  that I have declared at the package level. Now inside the exec sql tak, I am calling this variable. Now when I try to execute this task, it fails and I get the following:

```
[Execute SQL Task] Error: Executing the query "EXEC CTL_ISRT_A 55,1" failed with the following error: 
"Could not find stored procedure 'CTL_ISRT_A'.". Possible failure reasons: Problems with the query, 
"ResultSet" property not set correctly, parameters not set correctly, or connection not established correctly.
```

There is a stored procedure called "CTL_ISRT_A" in the db and I am able to execute it from SQL Server. This sp is inserting a new row in the table and it returns @@IDENTITY. Basically I need to store an integer value after the insert happens to a variable.

I tried setting the result set to a 'Single Row' and tried assigning the value to a variable but it didn't help. Could someone help me here?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Problem with the component configuration. Can you post the screen with each tab from you SQL Task, becouse there is several errors that may couse this error. As for now, did you try to use "dbo.CTL_ISRT_A" insted of "CTL_ISRT_A"?

Comment: I tried executing the stored procedure without the variable and it still gives me the same error.

Comment: I mean the "dbo" before the proc name. Note that in the error there is: EXEC CTL_ISRT_A 55,1 so it means that your variables is sending and accesable. The problem is than with an procedurę name or result set.

Comment: Inside the variable, there is no "dbo" before the sp name. Do I need to add that? And I am sure that the proc name is given correctly. As I said before, if I take the value of the variable (EXEC CTL_ISRT_A 55,1) and run it in sql server, it works! In the exec sql task, I have used Variable as the SQLSourceType and selected this variable that I created. And in the result set page, I selected another variable to hold the identity from the table (the result set name is the column name from the table where the row is getting inserted)

Comment: I've uploaded the screen grabs

Comment: Thanks for your help, I have managed to fix the issue. Apparently, the sp was created under a different schema and not under "dbo".

Now there is a small issue. Inside the sp, after the insert happens, there is a select @@IDENTITY statement at the end. I need to assign this to another variable. 

However, when I create a result set to assign the value to a variable, I get the following:

Error: No result rowset is associated with the execution of this query.

[Execute SQL Task] Error: An error occurred while assigning a value to variable "LOAD_ID": "Exception from HRESULT: 0xC0015005".

Answer (score 0):

I got a fix to this. Modified the stored procedure code and it began to work.